# What determines the combination of ciphers available on an SSL server?

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, authentication, ssl-certificate

I have a site that has been bound to a new SSL certificate with SAN (4 additional names). 
The certificate has a 2048-bit key.

The problem is that it works on some browser/OS combinations but not on others.

- IE7 / Win XP - fail
- IE6 / Win 2003 - fail
- IE8 / Win XP / Corporate proxy - OK
- IE8 / Win 7 / OTHER Corporate proxy - fail
- IE9/10 / Win 7 - OK
- Chrome / Win 7 - OK
- Firefox / Win 7 - OK
- Chrome / Android - OK

Note: The two corporate proxies are very different organisations, in two separate countries.

I have installed Fiddler on the IE6 / Win 2003 (2nd on the list) and have captured this from the Inspectors\Raw tab:

IE6:

```
CONNECT sorry.site.not.disclosed:443 HTTP/1.0
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; FDM; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Host: sorry.site.not.disclosed
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

A SSLv2-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Major Version: 2
Minor Version: 0
Random: EA AE EB C5 20 0C 46 90 7F C1 E0 EE 47 BE 05 63
SessionID: empty
Ciphers: 
    [10080] SSL2_RC4_128_WITH_MD5
    [700C0] SSL2_DES_192_EDE3_WITH_MD5
    [30080] SSL2_RC2_128_WITH_MD5
    [60040] SSL2_DES_64_WITH_MD5
    [20080] SSL2_RC4_128_EXPORT40_WITH_MD5
    [40080] SSL2_RC2_128_EXPORT40_WITH_MD5
    [00FF]  TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV

Compression: 
(not specified)
Extensions: 
    none
```

Chrome:

```
CONNECT sorry.site.not.disclosed:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: sorry.site.not.disclosed
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/25.0.1364.172 Safari/537.22

A SSLv3-compatible ClientHello handshake was found. Fiddler extracted the parameters below.

Major Version: 3
Minor Version: 2
Random: 51 4A 0D 68 FE C4 50 A9 26 43 9E 1A C2 E9 05 5C FE 5F CF 37 4D 20 96 FF 0E 2F 5E EB 16 C1 F2 20
SessionID: empty
Ciphers: 
    [C014]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0088]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
    [0087]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
    [0039]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [0038]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_SHA
    [C00F]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
    [0084]  TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
    [0035]  TLS_RSA_AES_256_SHA
    [C011]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [C013]  TLS1_CK_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [0045]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
    [0044]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
    [0066]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [0033]  TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [0032]  TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_SHA
    [C00C]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [C00E]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
    [0096]  TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA
    [0041]  TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
    [0005]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
    [0004]  SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
    [002F]  TLS_RSA_AES_128_SHA
    [C012]  TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
    [0016]  SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [0013]  SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [C00D]  TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
    [FEFF]  SSL_RSA_FIPS_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA
    [000A]  SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_SHA

Compression: 
    [00]    NO_COMPRESSION

Extensions: 
    server_name sorry.site.not.disclosed
    renegotiation_info  00
    elliptic_curves 00 06 00 17 00 18 00 19
    ec_point_formats    01 00
    SessionTicket TLS   empty
    NextProtocolNegotiation empty
    channel_id(GoogleDraft) empty
    status_request  01 00 00 00 00
```

When testing using SSLLabs, e.g. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=mail.google.com

The site shows ONLY two options under cipher suites, and supports only TLS 1.0:

```
Protocols
TLS 1.2 No
TLS 1.1 No
TLS 1.0 Yes
SSL 3.0 No          
SSL 2.0 No

Cipher Suites (SSLv3+ suites in server-preferred order, then SSLv2 suites where used)
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH 256 bits (eq. 3072 bits RSA)                                128         
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH 256 bits (eq. 3072 bits RSA)
```

I have contacted Verisign (Australia) and the chap claims that all Verisign certificates support SSLv1, v2, v3, TLS.

So why does the IIS server not present it?  Using a SELF-SIGNED wildcard certificate, I was able to get the same IIS server to report on SSLLabs:

```
Protocols
TLS 1.2  No 
TLS 1.1  No 
TLS 1.0  Yes 
SSL 3.0  Yes
SSL 2.0   INSECURE           Yes

Cipher Suites (SSLv3+ suites in server-preferred order, then SSLv2 suites where used)
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x2f)          128         
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x35)          256         
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)      128         
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xa)         168         
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH 256 bits (eq. 3072 bits RSA)                128         
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH 256 bits (eq. 3072 bits RSA)                256         
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x4)     128         
SSL_DES_192_EDE3_CBC_WITH_MD5 (0x700c0)                168         
SSL_RC4_128_WITH_MD5 (0x10080)       128
```

Where to look next?

Comment: when you say it "doesn't work" - what exactly do you mean? it throws an invalid certificate error or?

Comment: Please see edit to question

Comment: that's odd that the protocols and ciphers would change - did you bounce the machine between cert changes? possibly you made some changes to the protocol and cipher settings and they only took affect on reboot?

Comment: typically you'd set the ciphers on/off under [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Ciphers]
"Enabled"=dword:ffffffff (on) or "Enabled"=dword:00000000 (off)

I've never seen different certs change the protocols and ciphers offered...

Comment: I can switch between the two at will, and the ciphers/protocols reported by ssllabs changes. Maybe that site's not trustworthy? It does match up with my own tests using Firefox enabling/disabling TLS.

Comment: Qualys is about as reputable as they come and i have previously used them to troubleshoot issues that the verisign scanner and OpenSSL scripts I had couldn't find... Still- something very odd is happening. Can you put up your cert properties minus identifying info ?

Comment: First, check if your Verisign certificate and your self-signed certificate are signed under the same SHA algorithm (SHA1 or SHA256 or SHAxxx above 256). If not, then create a self-signed certificate with the same algorithm as Verisign's and check again. It is possible that your Verisign cert's cryptography is plain incompatible with older protocols. (And while you are still at that, drop SSLv2 off your IIS FTGJ)

Answer (score 2):

On all Windows 2008 R2 servers that I've seen ssl v2 has been enabled by default and I've had to go and disable it myself. Doing so (disabling it) hasn't seemed to break IE6... obviously the machine has been hardened by someone

Qualys has a very decent online SSL scanner that will tell you exactly what protocols and even cipher suites you have enabled, and if there are any other cert errors and what renegotiation is allowed - https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ -  perhaps an overly limited combination of ciphers and protocols has been chosen.

When you say it fails - what do you mean? That there is a certificate error? Is the root CA trusted on the older client machines?

It is possible in IE to disable SSL v3 and other protocols, on those machines throwing errors, check in Tools / Internet Options / Advanced tab and see if SSL 3 and TLS 1 is checked.

Check the values of the following reg keys

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\DisableRenegoOnClient
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\DisableRenegoOnServer

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\AllowInsecureRenegoClients
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\AllowInsecureRenegoServers
```

see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/977377 and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980436